# How to integrating this PJAX with Material Design template and jquery plugin without any conflicts?

Tags: jquery, ajax, material-design, jquery-select2, pjax

I've been using pjax https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax to load page like this:

```
$(document).pjax('[data-pjax] a, a[data-pjax]', '#pjax-container');
```

But after page loaded, some Material Design components could not be displayed properly and some jquery plugins like select2, datepicker could not work properly too

How to integrate this PJAX with Material Design template and jquery plugin without any conflicts?